# How can I put the first two images on one column and the remaining two columns?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this sample:

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="slider" class="home-blocks en-slide">
    <div id="left-slide">
        <img alt="" src="http://www.moment-of-style.com/media/wysiwyg/5_1.jpg" style="display: none;" id="full-banner">
        <img alt="" src="http://www.moment-of-style.com/media/wysiwyg/444_1.jpg" style="display: none;">
        <img alt="" src="http://www.moment-of-style.com/media/wysiwyg/25.jpg" style="display: inline;">
    </div>
    <div id="right-slide">
        <img alt="" src="http://www.moment-of-style.com/media/wysiwyg/17.jpg" style="display: none;">
        <img alt="" src="http://www.moment-of-style.com/media/wysiwyg/22.jpg" style="display: none;">
        <img alt="" src="http://www.moment-of-style.com/media/wysiwyg/1.jpg" style="display: inline;">
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.home-blocks{
    margin:0 auto;
    height:740px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#left-slide{
    width:47.5%;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#right-slide{
    float:right;
    width:47.5%;
}

#right-slide img,#left-slide img{
    width:100%;
}

.full-banner{
    width:100% !important;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```js
if (jQuery('#slider').hasClass('en-slide')) {
    //For the first 2 images I want to add class full banner. The rest has to be as they are now.
}
```

I want to do first two big pictures. I want to remove class `.left-slide` and add class `.full-banner` just for the first two pictures.

I tried so, but unfortunately does not happen what they want.

```js
    jQuery('#left-slide').addClass('full-banner');
} else {
    jQuery('#left-slide').removeClass('full-banner');
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does the provided answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

By using `#left-slide` you are targeting the wrapper DIV. To target the first images in both `#left-slide` and `#right-slide` and give them the class `full-banner` you should do

```
$('#left-slide').children().first().addClass('full-banner');
$('#right-slide').children().first().addClass('full-banner');
```

I hope I understood the question correctly.